# Remove rows based on a value in second last column in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a text file that I need to trim based on a value in the second last column - if it says 1, delete the line, if 0, keep the line.

The text looks like this, it just has thousands of rows:

```
          #name        #bunch of values                    #column of interest

    00051079+4547116 00 05 10.896 +45 47 11.570              0 0 \n
    00051079+4547117 00 05 10.896 +45 47 11.570     432   3  0 0 \n
    00051079+4547118 00 05 10.896 +45 47 11.570  34     6    1 0 \n
```

I have tried this (plus about a hundred variations of this):

```
with open("Desktop/MStars.txt") as M:
    data = M.read()

data = data.split('\n')

mactivity = [row.split()[-2] for row in data]
#name = [row.split(' ')[0] for row in data]

#print ((mactivity))

with open("Desktop/MStars.txt","r") as input:
    with open("Desktop/MStarsReduced.txt","w") as output: 
        for line in input:
            if mactivity =="0":
                output.write(line)
```

Thank you in advance, it is driving me mad.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that a line from a CSV reader is a list, where each cell/column is another value.

Editing your last little code block:

```
with open("Desktop/MStars.txt","r") as input:
    with open("Desktop/MStarsReduced.txt","w") as output: 
        for line in input:
            if line[-2] == 0:
                output.write(line)
```

This will write your line if and only if the second to last field is 0. Otherwise, it will not be written.